# Graph Lines cross the Y axis on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I noticed that there was an [issue opened up for IE8 for this issue on the google code page for dygraphs](https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=134). It mentioned something about excanvas.js but from what I can tell in the current version of dygraphs excanvas.js has been removed.

The only time I see this issue is when I load the page on a mobile. I also noticed the title covers the top portion of the graph. I am not sure if the last one can be solved but I am hoping there is a solution for lines on the Y axis.

[image: Graph in mobile view]

Comment: Do you see this specifically on Android? dygraphs is working around a pretty catastrophic bug in older Android browsers, see [this issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/608). If you're using Chrome, then perhaps it's time for the check needs to be made more specific.

Comment: I did see this issue on an android device. I tested on both Chrome and Firefox for android. Both browsers had lines being drawn on the Y axis labels. The picture above is from the Firefox browser.

Comment: Yeah, so the issue is that [this check](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/bf50de0db3094fc5155efc8aee14112df2545e42/src/dygraph-utils.js#L679-L687) needs to be made more precise. It should look for the old Android browser only, not just any Android device.

Comment: I was able to force that check to always evaluate to false and the charts look much better on mobile. Should I open a ticket on this issue?

Comment: Just subscribe to the one I linked to in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this issue (which seems to only affect Dygraphs 1), here is the work-around used on a legacy project (that can't upgrade to Dygraphs 2).

The isAndroid() function is called only one place in the code, specifically in a work-around for the Android browser (which inadvertently breaks graph functionality for ALL Android devices, regardless of browser).

You can simply always have the function return `false` without any loss of functionality for most devices -- this presumably breaks functionality for the Android browser, but -- at last checking (June 2018) -- it's only about 2% of web browser market share.

```js
Dygraph.isAndroid = function() {
  return false
}
```